# How can I correctly catalog this partition problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, mathematical-modeling, set-partition

I am trying to properly catalog a type of partition problem I have defined. I would like to know the name of these type of problems so I can do some more research. Initially I think that it might be referred as follows:

> [Partition Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) > multi-way partition problem
>
> Which is defined as (Wikipedia) "the optimization version of the partition problem. Here, the goal is to divide a set or multiset of $n$ integers into a given number $k$ of subsets, minimizing the difference between the smallest and the largest subset sums."

For that reason I am using as a lead paper to gather ideas:  "Korf, Richard E. (2009). [Multi-Way Number Partitioning (PDF)](http://ijcai.org/papers09/Papers/IJCAI09-096.pdf). IJCAI."

Specially the introduction states that

"...the number partitioning problem is to divide them into a collection of mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive subsets so that the sum of the numbers in each subset are as nearly equal as possible."

But I am not really sure if my defined problem could be included in that kind of generic problems. Here is the description / algorithm of the problem:

> 1. Initially there is a FIFO set $F$ and an empty list $S$ of subsets. Every time a subset is generated it will have an index $i$, for instance $S_i$. The first subset will be $S_0$, then $S_1$, etc. The main rule is that in every moment the sum of the elements of any $S_j$ will be smaller or equal to the sum of the elements of any $S_i$ with an index $i$ smaller than $j$.
> 2. Take the head element of the FIFO set and
>
> > a) If the sum of the elements of the subset with greatest index $S_k$ is greater or equal to the new element, then create a new subset $S_{k+1}$ and insert the element.
> >
> > b) If not, then insert the element in the existing subset $S_j$ with the greatest possible index $j$ such as when the element is aggregated the sum of the subset $S_j$ is still smaller or equal than any sum of any subset $S_i$ with lower index $i$ than $j$. If no subset with index greater than $0$ complies with the rule, then the element is inserted into $S_0$ (if $S_0$ still was not generated, it is created and then the element is inserted).
>
> 3. Repeat from step $2$ until the FIFO set is empty.

After some repetitions of this algorithm, the subsets look like this:

[image]

The first generated subset, $S_0$, is the one on the top, them the $S_1$ is below, and so on. The previously generated subsets will always have a sum greater or equal than any other lately generated subsets. There are two interesting subsets there, $S_0$ and the set of first elements of each $S_i$, I will call it $F$.

$S_0=\{1,2,4,5,8,12,17,19...\}$. $S_0$ will always be the subset with the greatest value of the sum of its elements.

$F=\{1,3,7,11,16,25...\}$. The elements of this subset are those elements of the initial FIFO set capable of forcing the generation of a new subset.

Tried to find them at OEIS, but unluckily they are not included.

I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. How could I catalog this kind of subset problem? Is it valid to assimilate a FIFO as a set?
> 2. If it can not be cataloged as a subset problem, is there another kind of problems managing this kind of models?

**UPDATE (2016/5/16)**: to understand better the problem I have tried to do an easier version in which there is a restriction in the quantity of subsets that can be generated: only two subsets are allowed, $S_0$ and $S_1$. Applying the algorithm the result after some iterations is as follows:

[image]

And fortunately for this version there is some information at OEIS! The elements marked in the first subset ($S_0$, upper subset) are exactly the sequence [A007051](http://oeis.org/A007051). So the subsets for a $2$-subset problem can be obtained by calculation of that sequence.

Comment: I think step 2a of the algorithm should say "*greater or equal*" rather than "*smaller or equal*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor thank you for the review!! yes it was a typo, now is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got a clue: it might be a special complex case of the "[Coins in a Fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coins_in_a_fountain)" problem! It requires some slight changes but I think it could fit in that category.

> "...arrange $n$ coins with $k$ coins at the base such that all the coins above the base layer touch exactly two coins of the lower layer."

Point $2$ can be rewritten as:

> 2. Take the head element of the FIFO set (e.g. $k$) and that will represent $k$ coins at once. Then I put them **all at once in the same  line**. For instance if I take $k=7$ from the FIFO pile. That means that I will put $7$ coins in the fountain but all in the same layer following the rules of a coins fountain problem.
>
> > a) If the sum of the elements of the subset with greatest index $S_k$ is **greater than** the new element, then create a new subset $S_{k+1}$ and insert the element.

So a **subset** of my problem is equivalent to a **layer** of the fountain.

In the classic problem $f(n,k)$ is decided beforehand: A $f(n,k)$ problem implies setting $n$ coins in a fountain whose base has $k$ coins. In my problem each layer will dynamically grow when the coins are taken from the FIFO pile and are set in different layers according to the coins in a Fountain rule. So it is a kind of "Coins in a Fountain" problem in which we add each time $k=1,2,3,4,5...$ coins at once and each time we add them we add them all together in the same layer, such all the coins of the layer must touch exactly two coins of the lower layer.

My initial setup of the problem does not force touching $2$ coins, but with the changes I did it fits the definition.

Now the layers look like this (the base layer of the fountain is on the top), the total number of coins of each layers is the sum of the elements of each layer:

[image]

For instance, the base layer has $1+2+3+5+8+9+...$ coins, the second layer $4+6+10+14+19+...$ coins, etc.

Now I can rethink the problem based on these premises!